# How to display the csv file name which is read by pandas read_csv() function?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to display the csv file name which is read by pandas.read_csv() function. I tried the below code but I couldn't display the csv file name.

```
import pandas as pd 
df=pd.read_csv("abc.csv") 
print(df.info())
```

I want to display the "abc". Guide me for my situation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you successfully read the file in the first place couldn't you assign a variable for the file name to be used later on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pandas.read_csv()` method accepts a `File` object (actually any file-like object with a `read()` method).

And the `File` class has a `name` object that has the name of the opened file.

I see this code and situation as absolutely meaningless since you already know the file name beforehand, but for the sake of completeness, here you go:

```py
import pandas as pd

csv_file = open("your_csv_filename.csv")
print(csv_file.name)
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
```

Comment: AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'file'

Comment: @user2585435 Thanks for the heads-up, I looked up the Python 2.x docs and got confused. Updated to reflect the Python 3 built-in `open()` function

Answer (score 0):

When you use pandas `read_csv` function, you get a dataframe that does not include the file name. So the solution is storing the name of the `.csv` in a variable, and then print it. You can check about pandas dataframe in [pandas.DataFrame Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)

```
import pandas as pd 
name = "abc.csv"
df=pd.read_csv(name) 
print(name.split(".")[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use something like this as read_csv does not save the file_name.
>
> Using glob will give you the ability to put wildcards or regex for all the CSV files on that folder for reading.

```
import glob

data = {}
for filename in glob.glob("/path/of/the/csv/files/*.csv"):
    data[filename.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]] = pd.read_csv(filename)

for key, value in data.items():
    print(key)
    print(value.info())
    print("\n\n")
```

`filename.split("/")[-1].split('.')[0]`

> The above line may look complicated but it just split the file_name 2 times.